# CSS not applying in masterpage

Tags: html, css, asp.net, master-pages

i am using masterpage in ASP.net. for the header and footer for which i have added some contents for header and footers in the head section of the masterpage i have referenced css files and in the ContentPlaceHolder i have refrenced a web form....when i run the wesite the css is not applied rather it shows error which i am not getting.

this is the image of the error:
[image: This is the error which i get]

here is the code for masterpage(MasterPage.master):

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>


    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="author" content="Aviators, http://themes.byaviators.com"/>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="wp-content/themes/realia/assets/img/favicon.png" type="image/png"/>
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11"/>
    <link rel="pingback" href="xmlrpc.php"/>

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="http://wp.realia.byaviators.com/wp-content/themes/realia/assets/js/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <![endif]-->

                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        var bhittani_plugin_kksr_js = { "nonce": "5e4653d004", "grs": false, "ajaxurl": "http:\/\/wp.realia.byaviators.com\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php", "func": "kksr_ajax", "msg": "", "fuelspeed": 400, "thankyou": "", "error_msg": "An error occurred", "tooltip": "0", "tooltips": [{ "tip": "", "color": "#ffffff" }, { "tip": "", "color": "#ffffff" }, { "tip": "", "color": "#ffffff" }, { "tip": "", "color": "#ffffff" }, { "tip": "", "color": "#ffffff" }] };
                </script>




                <link rel='stylesheet' id='bootstrap-css'  href='wp-content/themes/realia/assets/libraries/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.minf9b8.css?ver=4.0' type='text/css' media='all' runat="server"/>

                <link rel='stylesheet' id='bootstrap-responsive-css'  href='wp-content/themes/realia/assets/libraries/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.minf9b8.css?ver=4.0' type='text/css' media='all' runat="server"/>

                <link rel='stylesheet' id='chosen-css'  href='wp-content/themes/realia/assets/libraries/chosen/chosenf9b8.css?ver=4.0' type='text/css' media='all' />

                <link rel='stylesheet' id='colorbox-css'  href='wp-content/themes/realia/assets/libraries/colorbox/example1/colorboxf9b8.css?ver=4.0' type='text/css' media='all' />

                <link rel='stylesheet' id='general_variant-css'  href='wp-content/themes/realia/assets/css/realia-bluef9b8.css?ver=4.0' type='text/css' media='all' />

                <link rel='stylesheet' id='style-css'  href='wp-content/themes/realia/stylef9b8.css?ver=4.0' type='text/css' media='all' />

                <script type='text/javascript' src='wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery90f9.js?ver=1.11.1'></script>

                <script type='text/javascript' src='wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min1576.js?ver=1.2.1'></script>

                <script type='text/javascript' src='wp-content/plugins/kk-star-ratings/js.min7793.js?ver=2.4'></script>

                <script type='text/javascript' src='wp-content/plugins/revslider/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min17d1.js?rev=4.6.0&amp;ver=4.0'></script>

                <script type='text/javascript' src='wp-content/plugins/revslider/rs-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min17d1.js?rev=4.6.0&amp;ver=4.0'></script>

                <link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="xmlrpc0db0.php?rsd" />

                <link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" /> 

                <meta name="generator" content="WordPress 4.0" />

                <link rel='shortlink' href='index.html' />

                <style>
.kk-star-ratings { width:120px; }

.kk-star-ratings .kksr-stars a { width:24px; }

.kk-star-ratings .kksr-stars, .kk-star-ratings .kksr-stars .kksr-fuel, .kk-star-ratings .kksr-stars a { height:24px; }

.kk-star-ratings .kksr-star.gray { background-image: url(wp-content/plugins/kk-star-ratings/gray.png); }

.kk-star-ratings .kksr-star.yellow { background-image:url(http://wp.realia.byaviators.com/wp-content/plugins/kk-star-ratings/yellow.png); }

.kk-star-ratings .kksr-star.orange { background-image: url(http://wp.realia.byaviators.com/wp-content/plugins/kk-star-ratings/orange.png); }</style>

                <script type="text/javascript">var icl_lang = 'en'; var icl_home = 'index.html';</script>

                <script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/res/js/sitepress.js"></script>

                <meta name="generator" content="WPML ver:2.9.1 stt:1,4,3;0" />

                <link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr-FR" href="fr/index.html" />

                <link rel="alternate" hreflang="de-DE" href="de/index.html" />

                <link rel="stylesheet" href="#" type="text/css" id="color-variant">

                <title>Welcome to Our Website!</title>

                <link rel="stylesheet" href="wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/res/css/language-selectorb253.css?v=2.9.1" type="text/css" media="all" />













</head>
<body class="home page page-id-53 page-template page-template-page-properties-grid-php  header-light color-blue pattern-none layout-wide ">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">



        <div id="wrapper-outer">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="wrapper-inner">
            <div class="header-top-wrapper">
                <div class="header-top">
                        <div class="breadcrumb-wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span12">
                                                                <div class="breadcrumb pull-left">
                                                            <!-- Breadcrumb NavXT 5.1.1 -->
Realia
                                                    </div><!-- /.breadcrumb -->

                                                                <div class="account pull-right">

</ul></div>

                        </div>
                                    </div><!-- /.span12 -->
            </div><!-- /.row -->
        </div><!-- /.container -->
    </div><!-- /.breadcrumb-wrapper -->

                    <!-- HEADER -->
                    <div id="header-wrapper">
                        <div id="header">
                            <div id="header-inner">
                                <div class="container">
                                    <div class="navbar">
                                        <div class="navbar-inner">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="logo-wrapper span4">
                                                    <a href="#nav" id="btn-nav">Toggle navigation</a>

                                                                                                        <div class="logo">
                                                                                                                    <a href="index.html" title="Home">
                                                                                                                                                                                    <img src="wp-content/themes/realia/assets/img/logo.png" alt="Home">
                                                                                                                    </a>
                                                    </div><!-- /.logo -->

                                                                                                                                                                                                                            <div class="site-name">
                                                                <a href="index.html" title="Home" class="brand">
                                                                    Realia
                                                                </a>
                                                            </div><!-- /.site-name -->

                                                                                                                                                                                                                            <div class="site-slogan">
                                                                <span>Real estate & Rental <br>made easy</span>
                                                            </div><!-- /.site-slogan -->
                                                                                                                                                            </div><!-- /.logo-wrapper -->

                                                                                                    <div class="info">
                                                                                                                                                                            <div class="site-email">
                                                                <a href="mailto:info@byaviators.com">
                                                                    info@byaviators.com
                                                                </a>
                                                            </div><!-- /.site-email -->

                                                                                                                                                                            <div class="site-phone">
                                                                <span>333-444-555</span>
                                                            </div><!-- /.site-phone -->
                                                                                                            </div><!-- /.info -->


                                                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large list-your-property arrow-right"
                                                        href="my-properties/index.html">
                                                        List your property
                                                    </a>
                                                                                            </div><!-- /.row -->
                                        </div><!-- /.navbar-inner -->
                                    </div><!-- /.navbar -->
                                </div><!-- /.container -->
                            </div><!-- /#header-inner -->
                        </div><!-- /#header -->
                    </div><!-- /#header-wrapper -->
                </div><!-- /.top -->
            </div><!-- /.top-wrapper -->

            <!-- NAVIGATION -->
            <div id="navigation">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navigation-wrapper">
                        <div class="navigation clearfix-normal">
                            <div class="menu-main-container">
                                <ul id="menu-main" class="nav">
                                    <li id="menu-item-355" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent menu-item-has-children menu-item-355">
                                        <asp:HyperLink ID="NavHome" NavigateUrl="~/Index.aspx" runat="server">Home</asp:HyperLink>
                                      </li>
                                   <li id="menu-item-78" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menuparent menu-item-78"><asp:HyperLink ID="NavSale" NavigateUrl="~/properties.aspx" runat="server">Sale</asp:HyperLink>

                                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                                            <li id="menu-item-52" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-52"><a href="blog/index.html">Apartment</a></li>
                                            <li id="menu-item-148" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-148"><a href="right-sidebar/index.html">Commercial</a></li>
                                            <li id="menu-item-137" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-137"><a href="login/index.html">Residential</a></li>
                                            <li id="menu-item-149" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-149"><a href="left-sidebar/index.html">Land</a></li>

                                       </ul>

                                  </li>
                                  <li id="menu-item-78" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menuparent menu-item-78"><asp:HyperLink ID="NavPurchase" NavigateUrl="~/properties.aspx" runat="server">Purchase</asp:HyperLink>

                                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                                            <li id="menu-item-52" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-52"><a href="blog/index.html">Apartment</a></li>
                                            <li id="menu-item-148" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-148"><a href="right-sidebar/index.html">Commercial</a></li>
                                            <li id="menu-item-137" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-137"><a href="login/index.html">Residential</a></li>
                                            <li id="menu-item-149" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-149"><a href="left-sidebar/index.html">Land</a></li>
                                            <li id="menu-item-136" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-136"><a href="register/index.html">All</a></li>
                                       </ul>

                                  </li>
                                  <li id="menu-item-56" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-56"><asp:HyperLink ID="NavAgents" NavigateUrl="~/agents.aspx" runat="server">Agents</asp:HyperLink>
                                  </li>
                                  <li id="menu-item-56" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-56">
                                        <a href="agents/index.html">Construction</a>
                                  </li>
                                  <li id="menu-item-63" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-63"><asp:HyperLink ID="NavContact" NavigateUrl="~/contact-us.aspx" runat="server">Contact us</asp:HyperLink></li>
                            </ul>

                            </div>

                            <div id="icl_lang_sel_widget" class="widget icl_languages_selector"><div id="lang_sel"  >
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="lang_sel_sel icl-en">

            <img  class="iclflag" src="wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/res/flags/en.png" alt="en"  title="English" />                                
            &nbsp;English</a>                                    
            <ul>
                                                <li class="icl-fr">          
                    <a rel="alternate" hreflang="fr" href="fr/index.html">

                    <img  class="iclflag" src="wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/res/flags/fr.png" alt="fr" title="Français" />&nbsp;                    
                                        Français                    </a>
                </li>
                                <li class="icl-de">          
                    <a rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="de/index.html">

                    <img  class="iclflag" src="wp-content/plugins/sitepress-multilingual-cms/res/flags/de.png" alt="de" title="Deutsch" />&nbsp;                    
                                        Deutsch                    </a>
                </li>
                            </ul>            

                    </li>
    </ul>    
</div>
</div>                                                                                                                </div><!-- /.navigation -->
                    </div><!-- /.navigation-wrapper -->
                </div><!-- /.container -->
            </div><!-- /.navigation -->


    <!-- /.map -->
</div><!-- /.map-wrapper -->        </div><!-- /.top-inner -->

        </div>







    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>







<div id="wrapper-outer">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- /#wrapper-inner -->

                <!-- /.bottom-wrapper -->


            <div id="footer-wrapper">
                                    <div id="footer-top">
                        <div id="footer-top-inner" class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="span3">
                                    <div id="featuredproperties_widget-3" class="widget properties">

    <h2>Featured</h2>

<div class="content">
                        <div class="property">
    <div class="image">
        <a href="properties/3412-cloudcroft-dr-2-2/index.html"></a>
                    <img src="wp-content/uploads/2013/05/property-small-6-240x177.png" alt="3412 Cloudcroft Dr">
            </div>
    <!-- /.image -->

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="title">
            <h3><a href="properties/3412-cloudcroft-dr-2-2/index.html">
                                            3412 Cloudcroft Dr
                                    </a></h3>
        </div>
        <!-- /.title -->

        <div class="location">Jeff Blvd 1</div>
        <!-- /.location -->

        <div class="price">
                            Sold
                    </div>
        <!-- /.price -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.wrapper -->
</div>                    <div class="property">
    <div class="image">
        <a href="properties/3412-cloudcroft-dr-2-2/index.html"></a>
                    <img src="wp-content/uploads/2013/05/property-small-4-240x177.png" alt="1030 Palo Alto Ave">
            </div>
    <!-- /.image -->

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="title">
            <h3><a href="properties/3412-cloudcroft-dr-2-2/index.html">
                                            1030 Palo Alto Ave
                                    </a></h3>
        </div>
        <!-- /.title -->

        <div class="location">Palo Alto, SA</div>
        <!-- /.location -->

        <div class="price">
                            486000 €                     </div>
        <!-- /.price -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.wrapper -->
</div>                    <div class="property">
    <div class="image">
        <a href="properties/3412-cloudcroft-dr-2-2/index.html"></a>
                    <img src="wp-content/uploads/2013/05/property-small-3-240x177.png" alt="1041 Fife Ave">
            </div>
    <!-- /.image -->

    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="title">
            <h3><a href="properties/3412-cloudcroft-dr-2-2/index.html">
                                            1041 Fife Ave
                                    </a></h3>
        </div>
        <!-- /.title -->

        <div class="location">Palo Alto, SA</div>
        <!-- /.location -->

        <div class="price">
                            450000 €                     </div>
        <!-- /.price -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.wrapper -->
</div>            </div><!-- /.content -->

</div>                                </div>

                                <div class="span3">
                                    <div id="text-5" class="widget widget_text"><h2>Contact</h2>            <div class="textwidget"><table class="contact">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <th class="address">Address:</th>
        <td>1900 Pico Blvd<br>Santa Monica, CA 90405<br>United States<br></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="phone">Phone:</th>
        <td>+48 123 456 789</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="email">E-mail:</th>
        <td><a href="mailto:info@yourcompany.com">info@test.com</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="skype">Skype:</th>
        <td>your.company</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="gps">GPS:</th>
        <td>34.016811<br>-118.469009</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table></div>
        </div>                                </div>

                                <div class="span3">
                                    <div id="nav_menu-3" class="widget widget_nav_menu"><h2>Useful Links</h2><div class="menu-useful-links-container"><ul id="menu-useful-links" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-403" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-403"><a href="revolution-slider/index.html">Revolution Slider</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-206" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-206"><a href="fully-responsive/index.html">Fully Responsive</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-209" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-209"><a href="contact-us/index.html">Contact us</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-207" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-207"><a href="faq/index.html">FAQ</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-211" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-211"><a href="theme-customization-api/index.html">Customization API</a></li>
</ul></div></div>                                </div>

                                <div class="span3">
                                    <div id="text-6" class="widget widget_text"><h2>Say Hello!</h2>         <div class="textwidget"><div class="wpcf7" id="wpcf7-f28-o1" dir="ltr">
<div class="screen-reader-response"></div>
<form name="" action="http://wp.realia.byaviators.com/#wpcf7-f28-o1" method="post" class="wpcf7-form" novalidate="novalidate">
<div style="display: none;">
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7" value="28" />
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_version" value="3.9.3" />
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_locale" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="_wpcf7_unit_tag" value="wpcf7-f28-o1" />
<input type="hidden" name="_wpnonce" value="732d5d9ba2" />
</div>
<div class="control-group name">
<div><label class="control-label">Name<span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label></div>
<div class="controls">
                                             <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name"><input type="text" name="your-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" /></span>
                                        </div>
<p><!-- /.controls -->
                                    </div>
<p><!-- /.control-group -->
<div class="control-group email">
<div><label class="control-label">Email<span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label></div>
<div class="controls">

                                                                            </ul>
                                </div><!-- /.content -->
                            </div><!-- /.span6 -->
                        </div><!-- /.row -->
                    </div><!-- /#footer-inner -->
                </div><!-- /#footer -->
            </div><!-- /#footer-wrapper -->
        </div><!-- /#wrapper-outer -->
    </div><!-- /#wrapper -->

            <!-- /.palette -->    
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var _gaq = [["_setAccount", "UA-39841036-2"], ["_trackPageview"]];
                (function (d, t) {
                    var g = d.createElement(t), s = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0]; g.async = 1;
                    g.src = "../www.google-analytics.com/ga.js";
                    s.parentNode.insertBefore(g, s)
                }(document, "script"));
        </script>

</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/scripts657a.js?ver=3.9.3'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='wp-content/themes/realia/assets/libraries/colorbox/jquery.colorboxf9b8.js?ver=4.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='wp-content/themes/realia/assets/js/jquery.bxslider.minf9b8.js?ver=4.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=true&amp;libraries=places&amp;ver=4.0'></script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='wp-content/themes/realia/assets/js/bootstrap.minf9b8.js?ver=4.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='wp-content/themes/realia/assets/js/retinaf9b8.js?ver=4.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='wp-content/themes/realia/assets/js/gmap3.clustererf9b8.js?ver=4.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='wp-content/themes/realia/assets/libraries/chosen/chosen.jquery.minf9b8.js?ver=4.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='wp-content/themes/realia/aviators/plugins/properties/assets/js/aviators-mapf9b8.js?ver=4.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='wp-content/themes/realia/assets/libraries/iosslider/_src/jquery.iosslider.minf9b8.js?ver=4.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='wp-content/themes/realia/assets/js/jquery.cookief9b8.js?ver=4.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='wp-content/themes/realia/assets/js/jquery.ezmarkf9b8.js?ver=4.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='wp-content/themes/realia/assets/js/carouself9b8.js?ver=4.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='wp-content/themes/realia/assets/js/realiaf9b8.js?ver=4.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='wp-includes/js/comment-reply.minf9b8.js?ver=4.0'></script>



    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What happens if you comment out that line completely?

Comment: can you post the relevant css? and how are you 'referencing the css'

Comment: Get rid of the hyphens/dashes (`-`) from the ID attributes (or use underscores instead). See the remarks on this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.id.aspx

Comment: Also, if you want the references to work on all pages start your href with an app relative url if the wp-content is under the root of the app like so: href="~/wp-content. If it's at the root of the domain just use href="/wp-content as that always references the domain root.

Comment: @JamieDunstan....it works but the problem now is that when i click the hyperlink between the header and footer it navigates to the provided url without showing the header and footer

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly what it says it is. "bootstrap-css" is NOT a valid identifier. Try giving it a different ID.

Comment: yes it is but it does not accepts the dash '-'
if you apply underscore '_' instead of dash then it will work. :-)

Comment: Yep... because identifiers cannot have the dash but they CAN have the underscore.