# What's the use of <link rel="stylesheet" href="#" type="text/css" id="color-variant">?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've spend hours of debugging because Mysqli Update command wouldn't produce an error, but also wouldn't update the database.

I've searched everywhere, tried everything and eventually peeled of every bit of the code to find the problem.

Now: it's a bootstrap based site on a HTML5 theme. In the head of the page there's this line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="#" type="text/css" id="color-variant">
```

When I delete this line, everything works fine! If I don't the database won't update...

I'm glad I finally found the problem and deleting the line doesn't seem to do anything wrong with the site, but what is the use of this line? Why is it even there?

I'm happy everything works, but want to know why.

Comment: Removing it shouldn't hurt anything. It seems like a bug. With the `#`, it is pointing to the top page of the site as the URL for the stylesheet, which is meaningless. However, you might want to search the code for `color-variant` to see if it is used anywhere. It's possible that the code is replacing the `#` with an actual URL to dynamically load a stylesheet based on some specified color variant. Check the actual HTML in devtools to see if that has happened. The console might provide additional clues.

Comment: Maybe javascript is changing # to switch stylesheets? Int his case probably variant of colors

Comment: An HTML CSS tag will have no direct influence on mysqli queries. If anything, some Javascript in your site is interacting weirdly with this particular tag for whatever reason. You haven't dug deep enough yet.

Comment: I'd fire up a console and see if any JS errors are uncaught. If your site is interacting with your database through some ajax-calls, they might not be fired if your JS breaks. At first glance, that situation could look like there's something wrong with the database connection, but as @deceze says, it markup doesn't have any influence at all on how the server communicates with the database.

Comment: Are you using rulty by any chance? also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26017253/css-not-applying-in-masterpage

Answer (score 1):

There is no AJAX database connection. It is a site of which we had the HTML and design made by a company, after which I added the database connection, extra pages, etc.

The designer used a design by someone else (purchased off course) and redesigned it, so it would fit our company.

The code is full of unnecessary Javascript, css, etc. I deleted as much as I dared. I don't know much about Javascript, so I'm extra careful with that.

I found out that the original design was available in multiple colors, so I guess that's the reason that this part was still in the code. There was indeed some Javascript which adressed this ID, I deleted that part now.

Anyway, everything's working fine now. Thanks everyone for the hints!